# Creating a Microsoft Word Interop Document from Open Xml Document

Tags: c#, xml, openxml, office-interop

Trying to create an interop app from an open xml file. I'm using reflected code of a word file from Open Xml SDK. When i'm trying to insert xml of the Open Xml Document into interop document

```
doc.Range().InsertXML(package.MainDocumentPart.Document.OuterXml);
```

this line throws `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` which says XML cannot be inserted into that location.

Here is the full code

```
public void CreatePackage()
{
  using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
      CreateParts(package);
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Add(System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
      doc.Range().InsertXML(package.MainDocumentPart.Document.OuterXml);
      doc.Activate();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
public void CreatePackage()
{
  using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
      CreateParts(wordDocument);
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Add(System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
      XDocument xDoc = OPCHelper.OpcToFlatOpc(wordDocument.Package);
      string openxml = xDoc.ToString();                        
      doc.Range().InsertXML(openxml);
      doc.Activate();
    }
  }
}
```

To get the code of `OPCHelper` Class  You can take it from here [Utility to generate Word documents from template](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/314219/Utility-to-generate-Word-documents-from-template).

For more information Look at this one also [Transforming Open XML Documents to Flat OPC Format](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/09/29/transforming-open-xml-documents-to-flat-opc-format/)

Answer (score 0):

I would save the OpenXML to a temp file and use interop to open that file in Word. But I don't know if interop should or does support XML so I can't answer why InsertXML doesn't work. I suspect it doesn't expect OpenXML kind of XML, but something else.

Comment: The motive for doing this is starting the word file without saving as temp file. Thanks for answer but i have to do it without saving the file.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.insertxml%28v=office.14%29.aspx says nothing about OpenXML. An OpenXML document consists of 10+ different XML files. A single one of them doesn't make sense without the rest. One contains text, another contains styles, a third contains page and margin settings, etc.

Comment: Do i have any possibility for doing it without this way. I mean can I start the word document without saving it.